# Подключение libcurl

Tags: c++, c++builder, curl, link

Бьюсь уже не первый час с подключением `libcurl` под RadStudio XE. Скачал последнюю версию, добавил `#include "curl/curl.h"`, получил из библиотеки `libcurl.dll` lib-файл - добавил к проекту. Скинул 4 dll в system32:

- libcurl
- zlib1
- libeay32.dll
- ssleay32.dll

Билдер выдает ошибку линковки

> [ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '_curl_easy_init'
>   referenced from D:...

И все в таком духе...
Что может исправить эту проблему?

Comment: а проект у Вас 32 или 64битный? похоже что 64.

Comment: 32х битный. В XE нет возможности компилить 64х битные.

Comment: http://forum.vingrad.ru/forum/topic-323087.html

Comment: Благодарю. Либ-файл подошёл.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно прописать макроопределение

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
```

Затем подключить `libcurl.lib ws2_32.lib Wldap32.lib`
и `#include <curl\curl.h>`
Должно заработать.

Вот пример для визуалки

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#pragma comment( lib, "libcurl.lib" )
#pragma comment( lib, "ws2_32.lib" )
#pragma comment( lib, "Wldap32.lib" )
#include <curl\curl.h>
```

Comment: Человек же ясно сказал, что хочет подключить Curl как DLL. При чем здесь тогда `CURL_STATICLIB`?